# react-router v6 <Route /> component doesn't let me render <Navigate /> as an element

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm trying to make protected routes for my app, but **Route** component seems to not accept  as an element. I'm trying to:

```
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Navigate,
  Route,
  Routes,
} from 'react-router-dom';

...

<Router>
  <Routes>
    <Route
      path={DASHBOARD_PATH}
      element={
        <ProtectedRoute auth={customer?.isApproved}>
          <ScreensHome />
        </ProtectedRoute>
      }
   />
  </Routes>
</Router>
```

where  implementation looks like:

```
  const ProtectedRoute: React.FC<Props> = ({ children, auth }) => {
    if (!auth) {
      return <Navigate to={NOT_APPROVED_PATH} replace />;
    }

    return children;
  };
```

but receive: **[Navigate] is not a  component. All component children of  must be a  or <React.Fragment>** error
My dependencies file looks like that:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@azure/msal-browser": "^3.7.1",
    "@azure/msal-react": "^2.0.10",
    "@azure/storage-blob": "^12.17.0",
    "@date-io/date-fns": "^3.0.0",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.3",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@mui/material": "^5.15.6",
    "@mui/styles": "^5.15.6",
    "@mui/x-data-grid": "^6.19.1",
    "@mui/x-date-pickers": "^6.19.0",
    "@tanstack/react-query": "^5.17.19",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.11",
    "@types/node": "^20.11.6",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.48",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.18",
    "@types/react-phone-number-input": "^3.0.17",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.3",
    "axios": "^1.6.6",
    "date-fns": "^2.30.0",
    "draft-js": "^0.11.7",
    "draftjs-to-html": "^0.9.1",
    "env-cmd": "^10.1.0",
    "immutable": "^5.0.0-beta.4",
    "moment": "^2.30.1",
    "powerbi-client": "^2.22.3",
    "powerbi-client-react": "^1.4.0",
    "query-string": "^8.1.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-beforeunload": "^2.6.0",
    "react-calendly": "^4.3.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-draft-wysiwyg": "^1.15.0",
    "react-gtm-module": "^2.0.11",
    "react-moment": "^1.1.3",
    "react-phone-number-input": "^3.3.9",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.21.3",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "typescript": "^5.3.3",
    "web-vitals": "^3.5.1"
  },
```

what am I missing?

tried playing around with react-router-dom versions, implementing  in different ways but nothing seems to have helped

Comment: I don't see any issue with the code you have shared. Are you rendering a `Navigate` component somewhere else in your router? Can you [edit] to include a complete [mcve]? See if you can create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces this issue that we could inspect live.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

in **Routes** all children must be an **Route** , for protected route you can do this (also use **Outlet** instead of **children**):

```html
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Navigate,
  Route,
  Routes,
  useNavigate,
} from "react-router-dom";

export const AppRoutes = () => {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/sign-up" element={<SignUp />} />
      <Route path="/sign-in" element={<SignIn />} />
      <Route element={<ProtectedRoute />}>
        <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
        <Route path="/profile" element={<UserProfile />} />
        {/* Handle other routes */}
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  );
};

export const ProtectedRoute = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  //...
  if (!customer?.isApproved) {
    navigate(NOT_APPROVED_PATH);
  }
  return (
    <Grid container direction="column" width="100%" flexWrap="nowrap">
      <DashboardHeader />
      <Grid container direction="row" flexWrap="nowrap">
        <Grid item>
          <SideBar />
        </Grid>
        <Outlet />
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
};
```

Comment: in my example, all direct children of Routes are Route components. + this doesn't solve my issue with using Navigate component as an element as per documentation, my case should work, but somehow it doesn't. Also I tried using Outlet, but that didn't work either

Comment: component inside Routes like: <Route path={DASHBOARD_PATH} element={<Navigate to={getAdminPath(AdminType.USERS)} />} /> doesn't work as well(although it should)

Comment: for working Outlet you shoud do like this :

```<Route
          element={
            <ProtectedRoute auth={true}/>
            
          }
       ><Route
            path={"/dashboard"}
            element={
              <ScreensHome />
              
            }
        /></Route>```

Comment: so for showing Outlet you should use ProtectedRoute and ScreensHome in seprate nested Route

Comment: check [__this source__](https://github.com/rezamoosavidweb/protected-route)

Answer (score 0):

nevermind, I've probably overworked too much and didn't notice  tag right inside my  component at the bottom of the file. Thanks!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).